# value lookup is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have got a problem when I tired to compile my scala program with SBT.
I have import the class I need .Here is part of my code.

```
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileWriter
import java.io.PrintWriter
import java.io.IOException
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf,SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions
import scala.util.Random    
......
val data=sc.textFile(path)
    val kv=data.map{s=>
      val a=s.split(",")
      (a(0),a(1))
    }.cache()
    kv.first()
    val start=System.currentTimeMillis()
    for(tg<-target){
      kv.lookup(tg.toString)
    }
```

The error detail is :

```
value lookup is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, String)]
[error]           kv.lookup(tg.toString)
```

What confused me is I have import import org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions,
but it doesn't work . And when I run this in Spark-shell ,it runs well.

Answer (score 1):

`import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._` 
to have access to the implicits that let you use PairRDDFunctions on a RDD of type (K,V).
There's no need to directly import `PairRDDFunctions`

Comment: Thanks for you help.But I met new problem like this :[error] in package org.apache.hadoop which is not available.
    [error] It may be completely missing from the current classpath, or the version on
    [error] the classpath might be incompatible with the version used when compiling SparkContext.class.
    [error]     for(i<- 0 to totalnum-1){

Comment: That's a different question. Please create a new question for it. But it sounds like a classpath or version conflict, so check those carefully.